Addressing Ripple Voltage and Unequal DC Currents in AFE System
 We are operating a Variable Frequency Drive (VFD) fed from an Active Front End (AFE) via DC/DC converter. The AFE is directly connected to the grid via an AC transformer.
We’ve observed the following issues in our existing setup:
Significant ripple voltage between the DC bus terminals and ground, while the voltage between the positive (+) and negative (-) bus is pure DC.
The current across the positive and negative DC buses is not equal, with significant differences observed.
We’re looking for practical advice to address these issues in our existing, operational system, without the need for significant redesign.
Any insights or suggestions based on similar experiences would be greatly appreciated!

Please explain what the direction of the arrow indicates on your image alongside the $U_{dc}$ label. I don't see a transformer in your schematic. Is it your schematic because if it isn't you need to provide a web-citation for it.

The Arrow indicates the DC-link voltage

@AdisuTeshale please provide an image citation
